# Design-time xaml requires instance or avoid it?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, design-time

I have a problem I can not find how to solve the issue of the Design-time XAML, because it tells me: "**Object reference not set an instance of an object**".

Visual capture:
[image]

Here my fill of the list from Partial Class MainPage:
[image]

However, at compile time, it works correctly:
[image]

And after runtime, it works....

And my namespace of ViewModels where load return the list of "*Scenario*" class, instantiate not testify again as only get it built above. And I want to instantiate all my MainPage XAML when I just need a static list.

**Any way to solve this without instantiating the list in the constructor?** Or **what good practice recommend?** I want to work in Design-Time.

**EDIT:** To clarify, in the class: MainPage my control: MainWindow (sealed class, the capture is the partial kind of my sealed class) is where I think my static variable of type "**MainPage**", with the builder to "**this**" and that let me get elements.

[image]

Thousand Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has `MainPage.Current` value? I don't think... (like `Application.Current` is `null` in Design-time)

---

Edit: why do not use design time datacontext? d:DataContext

Comment: Yes! The variable of type "MainPage" current gets "this" in the constructor, which is the way I can get your items.

Example: 

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public static MainPage Current;

public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Current = this;
        }

Comment: Where do you set DataContext of Page (or any other anchestor of ListBox)

Comment: I'm instantiating a DataContext in XAML
<Page.DataContext><vm:MainPageViewModel/></Page.DataContext>
What difference would of user d:DataContext? I just want to reference my own MainPage as ViewModel. Thanks

Comment: I used to use blend Design-Time DataContext to create my UI only. In this case your DataContext is much more simple, contains only design relevant informations...

Comment: It was not the right fit, but you helped me get the right answer, I would say most appropriate method. Apparently "current" is instantiated in compilation mode, so in Design-time instantiation fails. Anyway, I tried in a separate class. Thank you.